# Complex Pivot data to rows and columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the data below which I want to pivot in SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE #TBL  
(
     Country VARCHAR(50),
     Category VARCHAR(50),
     Staff VARCHAR(50), 
     Quantity INT,
     Amount MONEY
)

INSERT INTO #TBL VALUES
('Australia ','Dairy Products ','Buchanan ',6,14),('Italy ','Cereals ','Peacock ',6,22),('Japan ','Cereals ','Suyama ',9,3),
('Japan ','Produce ','Peacock ',16,38),('Spain ','Cereals ','Peacock ',25,44),('Australia ','Produce ','Buchanan ',14,27),
('Italy ','Produce ','Suyama ',11,15),('Spain ','Cereals ','Leverling ',28,32),('Singapore ','Cereals ','Peacock ',2,43),
('Spain ','Cereals ','Suyama ',1,2),('Spain ','Produce ','Suyama ',25,50),('Spain ','Dairy Products ','Buchanan ',22,45),
('Australia ','Produce ','Suyama ',10,22),('Spain ','Dairy Products ','Leverling ',27,12),('Italy ','Produce ','Peacock ',16,7),
('Australia ','Cereals ','Peacock ',12,35),('Japan ','Dairy Products ','Buchanan ',13,17),('Australia ','Cereals ','Peacock ',29,37),
('Spain ','Cereals ','Leverling ',9,8),('Japan ','Cereals ','Peacock ',13,35);
```

I wrote the query below to pivot it. Note I need two pivots hence the double pivot in my Query

```
WITH Cat AS
(
SELECT Country  ,Category,  Amount FROM #TBL
) ,
 Staffs AS
(
SELECT Country  ,Staff, Quantity FROM #TBL
)  
SELECT * FROM Cat
PIVOT
(SUM(Amount) FOR Category IN (Cereals,[Dairy Products],[Produce]
)) p1

SELECT * FROM Staffs
PIVOT
(SUM(Quantity) FOR Staff IN ([Buchanan],[Leverling],[Peacock],[Suyama])
) pv2
```

When I execute the report I only have one part of the pivot and error msg

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 24
>   Invalid object name 'Staffs'.

with current output

```
Country    Cereals  Dairy_Products  Produce
--------------------------------------------
Australia   72.00   14.00           49.00
Italy       22.00   NULL            22.00
Japan       38.00   17.00           38.00
Singapore   43.00   NULL            NULL
Spain       86.00   57.00           50.00
```

I want it to look like this:

desired output

[image]

Any question, please ask?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  CREATE TABLE #TBL  (Country VARCHAR(50),Category VARCHAR(50),Staff VARCHAR(50), Quantity INT,Amount MONEY)
        INSERT INTO #TBL VALUES
        ('Australia ','Dairy Products ','Buchanan ',6,14),('Italy ','Cereals ','Peacock ',6,22),('Japan ','Cereals ','Suyama ',9,3),
        ('Japan ','Produce ','Peacock ',16,38),('Spain ','Cereals ','Peacock ',25,44),('Australia ','Produce ','Buchanan ',14,27),
        ('Italy ','Produce ','Suyama ',11,15),('Spain ','Cereals ','Leverling ',28,32),('Singapore ','Cereals ','Peacock ',2,43),
        ('Spain ','Cereals ','Suyama ',1,2),('Spain ','Produce ','Suyama ',25,50),('Spain ','Dairy Products ','Buchanan ',22,45),
        ('Australia ','Produce ','Suyama ',10,22),('Spain ','Dairy Products ','Leverling ',27,12),('Italy ','Produce ','Peacock ',16,7),
        ('Australia ','Cereals ','Peacock ',12,35),('Japan ','Dairy Products ','Buchanan ',13,17),('Australia ','Cereals ','Peacock ',29,37),
        ('Spain ','Cereals ','Leverling ',9,8),('Japan ','Cereals ','Peacock ',13,35);

        --SELECT * FROM #TBL

        SELECT Country  ,Category,  Amount,Staff, Quantity INTO #Cat FROM #TBL  --- create temp table for catgory data and insert cat data

        SELECT Country  ,Staff, Quantity INTO #Staffs FROM #TBL --- create temp table for staff data and insert staff data

        SELECT * INTO #CATEGORY FROM #Cat   --Create Pivot based on Catgories from #Cat table and insert data into #CATEGORY Data
        PIVOT
        (SUM(Amount) FOR Category IN (Cereals,[Dairy Products],[Produce]
        )) p1

        SELECT * INTO #STF FROM #Staffs --Create Pivot based on Staff from #Staffs table and insert data into #STF Data
        PIVOT
        (SUM(Quantity) FOR STAFF IN ([Buchanan],[Leverling],[Peacock],[Suyama]
        )) p2

        --- and final query here is your result 
        SELECT C.Country,SUM(C.Cereals) Cereals,SUM(C.[Dairy Products]) [Dairy Products],SUM(C.Produce) Produce,SUM(S.Buchanan) Buchanan,SUM(S.Leverling) Leverling,SUM(S.Peacock) Peacock,SUM(S.Suyama) Suyama FROM #CATEGORY C
        LEFT JOIN #STF S ON C.Country = S.Country
        GROUP BY C.Country

        drop table #TBL,#Cat,#Staffs,#CATEGORY,#STF
```

Answer (score 1):

Your expected result is not possible with `SQL`, but you can reach near what yo are looking for :

```
SELECT Country,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Category = 'Dairy Products' THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS [Category - Dairy Products],
       SUM(CASE WHEN Category = 'Cereals' THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS [Category - Cereals],
       SUM(CASE WHEN Category = 'Produce' THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS [Category - Produce],
       SUM(CASE WHEN staff = 'Buchanan' THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS [Staff - Buchanan],
       SUM(CASE WHEN staff = 'Leverling' THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS [Staff - Leverling],
       SUM(CASE WHEN staff = 'Peacock' THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS [Staff - Peacock],
       SUM(CASE WHEN staff = 'Suyama' THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS [Staff - Suyama]
FROM #TBL T
GROUP BY Country;
```

Data formation should be done at presentation layer instead of in `SQL`.

Answer (score 1):

Just another option is to `UNPIVOT` the data with a `CROSS APPLY`, and then use a single `PIVOT`

**Example**

```
Select *
 From  (
        Select Country
              ,B.*
         From  #TBL A
         Cross Apply ( values (Category,Amount) 
                             ,(Staff   ,Quantity)   -- >>> Corrected <<<
                     ) B (Item,Value)
       ) src
 Pivot (sum(value) for Item in ([Cereals],[Dairy Products],[Produce],[Buchanan],[Leverling],[Peacock],[Suyama]) ) pvt
```

**Returns**

[image]